# Stata: Order of legend items with multiple axes

Tags: graph, stata, legend-properties, multiple-axes

I am trying to simultaneously graph two axes using `twoway`. One axis uses the variable `route` to replace the usual symbol using `mlabel` and `msymbol(none)`. The other axis requires no specific label in the plot region, but ideally should be keyed in the legend as "Incr. Dose".

An undesired result arises when using the `legend(order)` specification to create the legend labels. The legend as coded has the symbol for the second axis as the 3rd ordered legend item. I would expect the code to place the symbol for the second axis as the 5th item. The problem can be fixed by adding a dummy category for an unused 5th `route` and moving the symbol by hand using the graph editor. I would like to know why the `legend(order)` option behaves this way, whether there is some interaction with `mlabel` or `msymbol(none)` and if a coding solution is available for use in repeated application.

```
*create data
clear 
set seed 42
set obs 50

gen cuml_dose = rnormal(0,1) *10 + 100
sort cuml_dose
gen interval = [_n] 
gen id = 1
gen incr_dose =0
replace incr_dose = cuml_dose[_n+1] - cuml_dose if [_n] > 1
gen route = rpoisson(1)
tab route,m

*create problem graph
sort interval
twoway  scatter cuml_dose interval, mlabel(route) msymbol(none) yaxis(1) || ///
    scatter incr_dose interval,  yaxis(2) ///
    legend(on) legend(order(0 "0=oral" 1 "1=IV" 2 "2=IM" 3 "3=patch"))

*partial solution
twoway  scatter cuml_dose interval, mlabel(route) msymbol(none) yaxis(1) || ///
    scatter incr_dose interval,  yaxis(2) ///
    legend(on) legend(order(0 "0=oral" 1 "1=IV" 2 "2=IM" 3 "3=patch" 4 "Incr. dose"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the self-contained example.

Consider

```
scatter cuml_dose interval, mlabel(route) ms(none) yaxis(1) /// 
|| scatter incr_dose interval, yaxis(2) ///
legend(on order(- "0 = Oral" - "1 = IV" - "2 = IM" - "3 = patch" 2 "Incr. dose"))
```

In your last graph,

1. `cuml_dose` is the first variable plotted: the fact that you use marker labels with several distinct values is irrelevant to the counting. So, it doesn't correspond to 0 to 3. I'm surprised that a reference to `0` is allowed in `order()`. Most crucially, marker labels are just text and `graph` doesn't care what the text is beyond showing it as instructed.
2. `incr_dose` is the second variable plotted: hence use `order(2` ... `)`.
3. You can add to the legend arbitrarily with dash syntax, as above.
4. I can't see that the use of two axes is problematic here at all to defining the legend. We're just counting what is plotted on any *y* axis.

Bottom line: count what is plotted on any *y* axis in order of mention of variables in the syntax.